Using different length of sequence as an input shape
As an example, my data shape is (100, 27, 1000), where 100 is the number of samples, 27 is the length of entire data sequence and 1000 is the number of features.
I want to use RNN to train the data, but for the input shape in the RNN model I want it to take (3, 1000) ie I want to be able to use different length of sequence instead of the 27.
One thing I tried to do was to change the shape of the data from (100, 27, 1000) to (10, 9, 3, 1000) and then change that to (90, 3, 1000).
I don't know if that is right. That only increases the number of samples.
I know the length of sequence is taken from the original data shape.
Any suggestion is welcome
